# CSS mouseover highlight table hyperlink

Tags: html, css, mouseevent, highlight, mouseover

I am using CSS3 `hover` effect and facing a problem about that for an element.

The problem is about when I point the mouse at one `th` (using `hover`), the color of `th` hyperlink the same of the background, so I need to make it change on that event.

Here a live **example**:

```css
.maps-btn tr {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.maps-btn tr:hover {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
.maps-btn a:hover {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="row">
        <table class="table table-bordered table_class maps-btn">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>1111</th>
                    <th>2222</th>
                    <th>3333</th>
                    <th>4444</th>
                    <th>5555</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="#">AAAA</a></td>
                    <td>BBBB</td>
                    <td>CCCC</td>
                    <td>DDDD</td>
                    <td>EEEE</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="#">FFFF</a></td>
                    <td>GGGG</td>
                    <td>HHHH</td>
                    <td>IIII</td>
                    <td>JJJJ</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div> 
</div>
```

And i wanna disable hover on thead. I wanna use hover on tbody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do like this:

```css
.maps-btn tr {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.maps-btn a {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.maps-btn tr:hover {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}

.maps-btn tr:hover a {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
.maps-btn a:hover  {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="row">
        <table class="table table-bordered table_class maps-btn">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>1111</th>
                    <th>2222</th>
                    <th>3333</th>
                    <th>4444</th>
                    <th>5555</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="#">AAAA</a></td>
                    <td>BBBB</td>
                    <td>CCCC</td>
                    <td>DDDD</td>
                    <td>EEEE</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="#">FFFF</a></td>
                    <td>GGGG</td>
                    <td>HHHH</td>
                    <td>IIII</td>
                    <td>JJJJ</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it like this. This works fine

```
.maps-btn tr, .maps-btn tr a {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.maps-btn tr:hover {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}
.maps-btn a:hover, .maps-btn tr:hover a {
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this style:

```
.maps-btn tr:hover a{
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your CSS a little. Include tbody as a selector.

```css
.maps-btn tbody tr {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.maps-btn tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.maps-btn tbody a:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-9">
  <div class="row">
    <table class="table table-bordered table_class maps-btn">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>1111</th>
          <th>2222</th>
          <th>3333</th>
          <th>4444</th>
          <th>5555</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="#">AAAA</a></td>
          <td>BBBB</td>
          <td>CCCC</td>
          <td>DDDD</td>
          <td>EEEE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="#">FFFF</a></td>
          <td>GGGG</td>
          <td>HHHH</td>
          <td>IIII</td>
          <td>JJJJ</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```